# redirection of the result in a file text

Tags: perl, file, redirect

I do a perl scrip that it  creates a hash directly from the contents of the first file, and then reads each line of the second, checks the hash to see if it should be printed.

Here is the perl script :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %permitted = do {
open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt';
map { /(.+?)\s+\(/, 1 } <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', 'f2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
my ($phrase) = /(.+?)\s+->/;
print if $permitted{$phrase};
}
```

I am looking for how i print the result in a file text because this script actually print the result on the screen.

Thank you in advance.

Cordially

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl thescript.pl > result.txt
```

Will run your script and put the printed output in `result.txt`

Or, from within the script itself:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %permitted = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt';
    map { /(.+?)\s+\(/, 1 } <$fh>;
};

# Open result.txt for writing:
open my $out_fh, '>', 'result.txt' or die "open: $!";

open my $fh, '<', 'f2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($phrase) = /(.+?)\s+->/;
    # print output to result.txt
    print $out_fh $_ if $permitted{$phrase};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a new filehandle in write mode, then print to it. See perldoc -f print or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html for more info

```
...
open my $fh, '<', 'f2.txt';
open my $out_fh, '>', 'output.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my ($phrase) = /(.+?)\s+->/;
  print $out_fh $_
      if $permitted{$phrase};
}
```

Comment: You actually need to specify `$_` explicitly, else it will print `GLOB(0x...)` to the terminal. So `print $out_fh $_ if ...`

Answer (score 2):

`map`ping the file contents first produces a list of all of the file's lines.  This isn't necessarily a bad thing, unless the file's substantially large.  [grebneke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2061321/grebneke) showed how to direct output to a file, using `> result.txt`.  Given this, and the (possible) `map` issue, consider just passing both files to the script from the command line, and process them using `while`s:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %permitted;

while (<>) {
    $permitted{$1} = 1 if /(.+?)\s+\(/;
    last if eof;
}

while (<>) {
    print if /(.+?)\s+->/ and $permitted{$1};
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl f1.txt f2.txt > result.txt`

Hope this helps!